# Is Notification Center available for web?

Tags: api, notification, sdk, web

The notification center is a feature that seems to exist only for mobile.
Am I wrong?

From what I read, the only way to get a notification center on the web is to call directly the API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_notifications_list.htm), aggregate the notifications and build by our own a customized interface. Am I right?

Thank you for your help.